# Creating Outlook Item in Excel Application generates error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below is the beginning of an Excel macro. I consistently get the message

> "Object doesn't support this property or method.

```vb
Sub RegisterAppointmentList(CName As String)

    ' adds a list of appontments to the Calendar in Outlook
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olApptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")

    Set olApptItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    On Error Resume Next
```

Comment: Should be `olApp.CreatItem()`.   `Application` when run in Excel refers to the Excel Application object.

Comment: `olApp.CreateItem` is what @TimWilliams probably means

Comment: The error occurs because the `Application` object doesn't have a property by the name of `CreateItem`. The `olApp` object does have such a property as @Tim Williams has pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
Set olApptItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

to

```
Set olApptItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

Comment: What does your answer add to what @Tim Williams wrote?